# User cannot log in, edit their profile or delete their account on LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

My username can be registered and it is stored in my database, but later it cannot be logged in Users who had been logged in before cannot edit their data either.
I have tried everything, visited many forums and watched many videos, please help
The last video I saw was one in which the user could simply change his password, I tried to do it and I couldn't either, if you could help me so that I could edit all his data

CODES:
WEB.PHP:

```
    <?php
    
    use App\Http\Controllers\UsuariosController;
    use App\Http\Controllers\PinturasController;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AdminController;
    use App\Http\Controllers\obrasController;
    use App\Usuario;
    use GuzzleHttp\Middleware;
    
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    
    // use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Web Routes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
    | routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
    | contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
    |
    */
    
    Auth::routes();
    
    Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index', 'middleware' => ['auth']])->name('home')
        ->middleware('auth');
    // Route::view('/', 'home')->name('home');
    
    Route::get('/usuarios', [App\Http\Controllers\UsuariosController::class, 'index']);
    Route::get('/pinturas', [App\Http\Controllers\PinturasController::class, 'index']);
    Route::get('/pintores', [App\Http\Controllers\PintoresController::class, 'index']);
    
    Route::get('/admin', [App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::class, 'index'])
        ->middleware('auth', 'auth.admin')
        ->name('admin.index');
    
    Route::get('/registerAdmin', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::class, 'create'])->name('register.index');
    Route::get('/registerAdmin', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::class, 'store'])->name('register.store');
    
    
    // REGISTRO DESDE FORMULARIO DE USUARIOS
    Route::get('/registrarse', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::class, 'index'])->name('register.index');
    Route::post('/registrarse', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::class, 'store'])->name('register.store');
    
    
    
    Route::get('/login', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::class, 'create'])->name('login.index');
    Route::post('/login', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::class, 'store'])->name('login.store');
    
    
    Route::get('/logout', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::class, 'destroy'])
        ->middleware('auth')
        ->name('login.destroy');
    
    
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'perfil', 'as' => 'perfil', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
            Route::get('/', function () {
                return view('perfil');
            });
    Route::get('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\PerfilController@index');
    Route::resource('usuarios', 'App\Http\Controllers\UsuariosController');
    
    // Route::get('NewPassword',[App\Http\Controllers\PerfilController::class,'NewPassword'])->name('NewPassword')->middleware('auth');
    // Route::post('/change/password',[App\Http\Controllers\PerfilController::class,'changePassword'])->name('changePassword');
    
    
    // Route::get('/eliminar', function ($id){
    //     Usuario::findOrFail($id)->delete();
    //     return redirect('/home');
    
    // });
    });
    
    Route::post('editar/Perfil', 'App\Http\Controllers\PerfilController@changePassword')->name('editar.Perfil');
    Route::post('eliminar/Perfil', 'App\Http\Controllers\PerfilController@destroy')->name('eliminar.Perfil');
    
    Route::get('/perfilArtista', [App\Http\Controllers\PerfilArtistaController::class, 'index'])->name('perfil.Artista');
    // Route::resource('obras',[App\Http\Controllers\ObrasController::class, 'index']);
    
    // AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADMIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIINNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
    
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
        Route::get('/', function () {
            return view('admin');
        });
        Route::get('/usuarios', 'App\Http\Controllers\UsuariosController@index');
        Route::post('/usuarios/editar', 'App\Http\Controllers\UsuariosController@editarUsuario');
        Route::resource('usuarios', 'App\Http\Controllers\UsuariosController');
    
    
        Route::get('/pinturas', 'App\Http\Controllers\PinturasController@index');
        Route::post('/pinturas/editar', 'App\Http\Controllers\PinturasController@editarPintura');
        Route::resource('pinturas', 'App\Http\Controllers\PinturasController');
    
    
        Route::get('/pintores', 'App\Http\Controllers\PintoresController@index');
        Route::post('/pintores/editar', 'App\Http\Controllers\PintoresController@editarPintor');
        Route::resource('pintores', 'App\Http\Controllers\PintoresController');
    });
    
    Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\ObrasController::class, 'obrasList'])->name('obras.list');
    Route::get('cart', [App\Http\Controllers\CartController::class, 'cartList'])->name('cart.list');
    Route::post('cart', [App\Http\Controllers\CartController::class, 'addToCart'])->name('cart.store');
    Route::post('update-cart', [App\Http\Controllers\CartController::class, 'updateCart'])->name('cart.update');
    Route::post('remove', [App\Http\Controllers\CartController::class, 'removeCart'])->name('cart.remove');
    Route::post('clear', [App\Http\Controllers\CartController::class, 'clearAllCart'])->name('cart.clear');
    
    Auth::routes();
    // Auth::routes();
```

LOGIN CONTROLLER:

```
<?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
    
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
    use Auth;
    use App\Usuario;
    
    class LoginController extends Controller
    {
        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Login Controller
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
        | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
        | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
        |
        */
        use AuthenticatesUsers;
    
        public function create()
        {
            return view('auth.login');
        }
    
        public function store()
        {
            if (auth()->attempt(request(['email', 'password'])) == false) {
                return back()->withErrors([
                    'message' => 'El email o la contraseña es incorrecto, por favor intentalo de nuevo'
                ]);
            } else {
    
                return redirect()->to('home');
            }
        }
        public function destroy()
        {
    
            auth()->logout();
    
            return redirect()->to('login');
        }
    }
```

LOGIN VIEW:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    
    <head>
    
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <link href="{{ asset('/css/login.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    
    
        <title>CHANI Login</title>
    
        <!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
        <link href="{{asset('/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2-gh-pages/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css')}}"
            rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link
            href="{{asset('/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2-gh-pages/https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i')}}"
            rel="stylesheet">
    
        <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
        <link href="{{asset('/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2-gh-pages/css/sb-admin-2.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
        @yield('css')
    
    </head>
    {{-- {{ route('login.store') }} --}}
    <body class="body text-center">
        <form method="POST" action="" class="form-signin">
            @csrf
            <a>
            <img class="mb-4" src="\css\img\chani.png" alt="" width="220" height="100">
            </a>
            <h1 class="h3 font-weight-normal">Bienvenido a Chani</h1>
    
            <label for="email" class="sr-only"> </label>
            <input class="form-control mt-4" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Correo Electronico"
                class="wCorreo  @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required
                autocomplete="email" autofocus>
    
            @error('email')
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </span>
            @enderror
    
            <label for="password" class="sr-only"></label>
    
            <input class="form-control mt-3" id="password" type="password" placeholder="Contraseña"
                class="wContra @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required
                autocomplete="current-password">
    
            @error('password')
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </span>
            @enderror
    
            <div class="checkbox mt-2">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}
                        style="color: black">
                    {{ __('Remember Me') }}
                </label>
            </div>
    
            <label for="registrase mt-2" class="sr-only"></label>
    
                    <a class="btn linkColor" href="{{ route('register') }}" style="color: #1cc88a; font-weight:600">
                        {{ __('Registrarse') }}
                    </a>
    
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block mt-2" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: #1cc88a">
                        {{ __('Iniciar Sesión') }}
                    </button>
    
                    @if (Route::has('password.request'))
    
                    <a class="btn mt-2 linkColor" href="{{ route('password.request') }}" style="color: #1cc88a; font-weight:600">
                        {{ __('¿No recuerdas tu contraseña?') }}
                    </a>
                    @endif
    
                    @error('message')
                    <p class="border border-red-500 rounded-md bg-red-100 w-full text-red-600 p-2 my-2">{{$message}}</p>
                @enderror
        </form>
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

PROFILECONTROLLER:

```
<?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Usuario;
    use Auth;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
    
    class PerfilController extends Controller
    {
        public function index()
        {
            return view('perfil');
        }
    
    
        public function changePassword(Request $request)
        {
            $usuario = Auth::user();
            $usuarioId = $usuario->id;
            $usuarioNombre = $usuario->Nombre;
            // $usuarioApellido = $usuario->Apellido;
    
            $usuarioEmail = $usuario->Email;
            $usuarioPassword = $usuario->password;
    
    
            if ($request->passwordActual != "") {
                $passwordNueva = $request->passwordNueva;
                $passwordConfirm = $request->passwordConfirm;
                $nombre = $request->nombre;;
                if (Hash::check($request->passwordActual, $usuarioPassword)) {
    
                    if($passwordNueva == $passwordConfirm){
                        if(strlen($passwordNueva)>=7){
                            $usuario->password = Hash::make($request->password);
                            $bbdd = DB::table('usuarios')
                            ->where('id',$usuario->id)
                            ->update(['password' => $usuario->password],['name' => $usuario->name],);
                            
                            return redirect()->back()->with('La contraseña se actualizo correctamente');
                        }else{
                            return redirect()->back()->with('La contraseña debe ser mayor a 7 caracteres');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
    
        public function destroy($id)
        {
            $usuario = Auth::user();
            $usuario = Usuario::find($id);
            $usuario->delete();
            return back()->with("El ususario se elimino correctamente");
        }
    }
```

USER PROFILE VIEW:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b41989f790.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link href="{{asset('/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2-gh-pages/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css')}}"
            rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link
            href="{{asset('/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2-gh-pages/https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i')}}"
            rel="stylesheet">
    
        <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
        <link href="{{asset('/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2-gh-pages/css/sb-admin-2.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
    
        <link href="{{asset('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet "
            integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3 " crossorigin="anonymous ">
    
        <link rel="" href="{{asset('/resources/js/bootstrap.js')}}">
    
        <link href="{{ asset('/css/perfil.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    
        {{--
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"> --}}
    
        {{--
        <link href="{{asset('/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2-gh-pages/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css')}}"
            rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> --}}
    
        {{--
        <link href="{{asset('/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2-gh-pages/css/sb-admin-2.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet"> --}}
    
        <title>Mi Perfil</title>
    </head>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light border-bottom">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/home">
                <img src="\css\img\chani.png" width="110" height="50" alt="">
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
                            data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Dropdown
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="derechita">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        @if(auth()->check())
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg iconosNav">
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping " style="color: #1cc88a; font-size:25px;"></i>
                            </button>
                            <a href="{{'/perfil'}}">
                                {{-- <button class="btn btn-sm" type="button" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: #1cc88a; display: inline-block;
                                    width: auto;
                                    vertical-align: middle;">
                                    <p style="margin-top:12px;">Bienvenido <b> {{auth()->user()->nombre}}</b></p>
                                </button> --}}
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg iconosNav">
                                    <i class="fa-solid fa-user " style="color: #1cc88a; font-size:25px;"></i>
                                </button>
                            </a>
        
                            @if (auth()->user()->role == 'admin')
                            <a href="{{'/admin'}}">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg iconosNav">
                                    <i class="fa-solid fa-user-gear " style="color: #1cc88a; font-size:25px;"></i>
                                </button>
                            </a>
        
                            
                            @elseif (auth()->user()->role == 'artista')
                            <a href="{{'/perfilArtista'}}">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg iconosNav">
                                    <i class="fa-solid fa-paintbrush " style="color: #1cc88a; font-size:25px;"></i>
                                </button>
                            </a>
        
                            @endif
        
                            @else
                            <a href="{{ route('login.index') }}">
                                <button class="btn btn-outline-success mr-2 my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit"> Registrate o
                                    Inicia
                                    Sesión</button>
                            </a>
        
                            @endif
                            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 ml-2">
                                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" style="box-shadow: none;
                                border:1px solid #ced4da;" type="search" placeholder="Buscar" aria-label="Search">
                                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit"
                                    style="box-shadow: none;background-color: #1cc88a; color:white; border:0px solid">Buscar</button>
                            </form>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    
    </header>
    
    <body>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="container rounded bg-white mb-5">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3 border-right">
                        <form>
                            @csrf
                            <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center text-center p-3 py-5"><img
                                    class="rounded-circle mt-5" width="150px" {{-- PONER FOTO --}}
                                    src="https://st3.depositphotos.com/15648834/17930/v/600/depositphotos_179308454-stock-illustration-unknown-person-silhouette-glasses-profile.jpg"><span
                                    class="font-weight-bold">{{Auth::user()->nombre}}</span><span
                                    class="text-black-50">{{Auth::user()->email}}</span><span> </span></div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5 border-right">
                        <form action="{{ route('editar.Perfil') }}" method="post">
                            @csrf
                            <div class="p-3 py-3">
                                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                    {{-- <h4 class="text-right">Bienvenido {{Auth::user()->nombre}}</h4> --}}
                                    <h4 class="text-right h3">Mi Perfil</h4>
    
                                </div>
                                <div class="row mt-1">
                                    <div class="col-md-6"><label class="labels">Nombre</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control " placeholder="{{Auth::user()->nombre}}"
                                            name="nombre" value="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6"><label class="labels">Apellido</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellido" value=""
                                            placeholder="Apellido">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row mt-1">
                                    <div class="col-md-12 mt-1"><label class="labels">Correo Electrónico</label>
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email"
                                            placeholder="{{Auth::user()->email}}" value="">
                                    </div>
    
                                    <div class="col-md-12 mt-1"><label class="labels">Numero de telefono</label><input
                                            type="text" class="form-control" name="telefono"
                                            placeholder="Número de teléfono" value=""></div>
    
                                    <div class="col-md-12 mt-1"><label class="labels">Contraseña Actual</label><input
                                            type="password" class="form-control" name="passwordActual"
                                            placeholder="Contraseña Actual" value=""></div>
    
                                    <div class="col-md-12 mt-1"><label class="labels">Nueva Contraseña</label><input
                                            type="password" class="form-control" name="passwordNueva"
                                            placeholder="Escribe tu nueva contraseña" value=""></div>
    
                                    <div class="col-md-12 mt-1"><label class="labels">Confirmar Nueva
                                            Contraseña</label><input type="password" class="form-control" name="passwordConfirm"
                                            placeholder="Confirma tu nueva contraseña" value=""></div>
    
                                    <div class="col-md-12 mt-1"><label class="labels">Nacionalidad</label><input type="text"
                                            class="form-control" name="nacionalidad" placeholder="Nacionalidad" value="">
                                    </div>
    
                                    <div class="col-md-12 mt-1"><label class="labels">Rol</label><input type="text"
                                        class="form-control" name="nacionalidad" placeholder="{{Auth::user()->role}}" value="">
                                </div>
    
                                    {{-- <div class="col-md-12"><label class="labels">Address Line 1</label><input
                                            type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="enter address line 1" value="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-12"><label class="labels">Address Line 2</label><input type="text"
                                            class="form-control" placeholder="enter address line 2" value=""></div>
                                    <div class="col-md-12"><label class="labels">Postcode</label><input type="text"
                                            class="form-control" placeholder="enter address line 2" value=""></div>
                                    <div class="col-md-12"><label class="labels">State</label><input type="text"
                                            class="form-control" placeholder="enter address line 2" value=""></div>
                                    <div class="col-md-12"><label class="labels">Area</label><input type="text"
                                            class="form-control" placeholder="enter address line 2" value=""></div>
                                    <div class="col-md-12"><label class="labels">Email ID</label><input type="text"
                                            class="form-control" placeholder="enter email id" value=""></div>
                                    <div class="col-md-12"><label class="labels">Education</label><input type="text"
                                            class="form-control" placeholder="education" value=""></div> --}}
                                </div>
                                <div class="mt-4 text-center"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary profile-button"
                                        style="background-color: #1cc88a; color:white;">Guardar Cambios</button></div>
                                <a href="{{ asset('/logout') }}">
                                    <div class="mt-3 text-center"><button class="btn btn-primary profile-button"
                                            type="button" style="background-color: #5d5d5d; color:white;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Cerrar Sesión &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</button></div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <form action="{{ route('eliminar.Perfil')}}" method="post">
                            <div class="mt-1 text-center"><button class="btn btn-primary profile-button"
                                    type="submit"
                                    style="background-color: #ff3737; color:white;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Elminar
                                    Cuenta&nbsp;&nbsp;</button></div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
    
                </div>
            </div>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: Any error messages or anomalies that could help us understand what is happening instead of just pasting whole files of code? [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: No error appears but users cannot log in or edit their data, its like the functions are not working, maybe i did them wrong

Comment: In you web.php, is this a type
you have an extra `});` that does not seem to actually be the end of something, is this a typo? That would make the edit routes break i suppose.

Comment: In what line do i have an extra "});"? If u are reffering to this line: 
    // });
    });    <----- THIS ONE below the commented lines
Its closing the function of  " Route::group(['prefix' => 'perfil', "